# Ifstream stops reading file after a few lines

Tags: c++, file, visual-c++

I am using an `ifstream` into a `stringstream` for reading a file but it stops after a couple lines...

```
string read(string filename)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filename);
    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << inFile.rdbuf();
    inFile.close();
    string str = strStream.str();
    return str;
}
```

This code stops after 'zh¬'
I am thinking maybe they are control characters in the ascii table, the first char after it stops is 26.
But i wouldn't think that matters.

Comment: What kind of file are you attempting to read? Is it a binary file? A text file? If it's a binary file that you open in text-mode (default) then on Windows the byte `26` is considered EOF (it corresponds to `Ctrl-Z`).

Comment: Your code seems OK, just make sure it's  an ASCII file. Supply extension of the files as well.

Comment: @seccpur file extension is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ifstream` is being opened in text mode. Try opening the file in binary mode:
`std::ifstream inFile(filename, std::ios::binary);`

> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into lines (zero or more characters plus a terminating '\n'). Whether the last line requires a terminating '\n' is implementation-defined. Characters may have to be added, altered, or deleted on input and output to conform to the conventions for representing text in the OS (in particular, C streams on Windows OS convert \n to \r\n on output, and convert \r\n to \n on input)
>
> - Data read in from a text stream is guaranteed to compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream only if all of the following is true:
>     the data consist only of printing characters and the control characters \t and \n (in particular, on Windows OS, the character '\0x1A' terminates input)
> - no \n is immediately preceded by a space character (space characters that are written out immediately before a \n may disappear when read)
> - the last character is \n
>
> A binary stream is an ordered sequence of characters that can transparently record internal data. Data read in from a binary stream always equals to the data that were earlier written out to that stream. Implementations are only allowed to append a number of null characters to the end of the stream. A wide binary stream doesn't need to end in the initial shift state.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes